# Why doesn't Cantor's Diagonal argument depend on the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice

I'm not really that familiar with AC, I've just started talking about it in my classes. But from what I understand, one of its formulations is that it is possible to create a set made from choosing elements from a series (potentially infinite) of other sets.
 Are we doing this in the Diagonal argument? We have a countably infinite number of sets (each with a real number) and we create a different one by choosing a digit from each of the subsets. 
Is this correct? Or am I misunderstanding AC, making some other error?

EDIT: It seems that someone asked which axioms of ZF did the argument use and it got answered. My question then becomes: Why doesn't Cantor's Diagonal argument depend on the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: In Cantor's argument, you can come up with a scheme that chooses the digit, for example 0 becomes 1 and anything else becomes 0. AC is only necessary if there is no obvious way to choose something. For example, if you have a surjective function $f:A\to B$ and you want to find an injective function $g:B\to A$. It seems obvious that you want $g(x)\in f^{-1}(x)$, but there is no obvious choice for which element it is.

Comment: If you're not really that familiar with AC, perhaps it would be wise to familiarize yourself with it *before* asking technical questions about it?

Comment: Cantor did not give an argument in terms of digits etc. He did give a proof of the uncountability of the reals (but he used topological arguments, essentially). His most famous theorem states that no surjection  $f: X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ exists (which uses no choice) and this *can* also be used to show uncountability of the reals (the Cantor set  in $[0,1]$ easily has the same size as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and so is uncountable.

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof? If so, what step seems to use the axiom of choice?

Comment: I've added another duplicate, which might answer your question more explicitly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thank you, the second duplicate answered my question. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome. Admittedly, that was the duplicate I thought was the one suggested. But as long as we got there reasonably fast, I guess it's fine. :)